# TCPDF only shows first character of string

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm newbie using TCPDF library and I'm having problems with `Write` and `MultiCell` functions. I don't know why sometimes TCPDF only prints the first character of the string given.

This is how it looks my `print_r($row)`

```
Array(
[0] => 
[codDefinitivo] => 
[1] => Best Spot
[seccion] => Best Spot
[2] => 
[colaboradora] => 
[3] => KELER
[marca] => KELER
[4] => KELER
[anunciante] => KELER
[5] => DIMENSION
[inscrito_pr] => DIMENSION
[6] => ARZAK Y KELER, HISTORIAS PARALELAS
[titulo] => ARZAK Y KELER, HISTORIAS PARALELAS
[7] => DIMENSION
[agencia] => DIMENSION
[8] => Bebidas alcohólicas
[categoria] => Bebidas alcohólicas
[9] => Nacer en Donostia, la pasión por el sabor y una apuesta por la intensidad son algunas de las características que Arzak  y Keler tienen en común.? El spot crea un paralelismo entre la vida de Arzak y la de Keler como referentes donostiarras del sabor y de la intensidad. Esta historia, puede ser narrada igualmente por keler, Y ese es el juego de la historia, el paralelismo entre los dos protagonista, la confusión, el ?de quien hablo?, de Juan Mari Arzak.. o de KELER.
[descripcion] => Nacer en Donostia, la pasión por el sabor y una apuesta por la intensidad son algunas de las características que Arzak  y Keler tienen en común.? El spot crea un paralelismo entre la vida de Arzak y la de Keler como referentes donostiarras del sabor y de la intensidad. Esta historia, puede ser narrada igualmente por keler, Y ese es el juego de la historia, el paralelismo entre los dos protagonista, la confusión, el ?de quien hablo?, de Juan Mari Arzak.. o de KELER.)
```

When I use the `$row['seccion']` or the `$row['descripcion']` the result is only the first character of both strings... I don't know what I'm missing.

This is how I coded the `Write` and `MultiCell` functions

```
$pdf->MultiCell (66, 10, $row['descripcion'], 0, 'L', false, 1, 75, 38, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
$pdf->Write(2, $row['seccion'], '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);
```

If I copy the content `$row[descripccion]` into the `MultiCell` function TCPDF outputs it correctly

```
$pdf->MultiCell (67, 10, "Nacer en Donostia, la pasión por el sabor y una apuesta por la intensidad son algunas de las características que Arzak  y Keler tienen en común.? El spot crea un paralelismo entre la vida de Arzak y la de Keler como referentes donostiarras del sabor y de la intensidad. Esta historia, puede ser narrada igualmente por keler, Y ese es el juego de la historia, el paralelismo entre los dos protagonista, la confusión, el ?de quien hablo?, de Juan Mari Arzak.. o de KELER.", 0, 'L', false, 1, 75, 38, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
```

The php script is the following
[...]

```
$result = mysql_query($sql,$link_kobal);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $pdf->SetFont($fontNameTitol, 'B', $tamanyFont);
    $pdf->Write(2, $row['seccion'], '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);

    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);


    // Descripció
    $pdf->SetXY(75, 35);
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 8);
    $pdf->Write(2, 'Descripción', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);

    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
    $pdf->MultiCell (67, 10, $row['descripcion'], 0, 'L', false, 1, 75, 38, true, 4, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
}
```

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Most likely your strings are line wrapped or truncated due to a small line width. Have a try playing around with the `strech` parameter to get a feeling.

Comment: @arkascha First of all thanks for your time and help. I tried the five values for strech parameter and goes worst because appears like it was an empty string.

Comment: That confirms that the available space simply is not enough for the string. You want to closely check your page and area setup. Can't help there, since you did not post your code, sorry.

Comment: What code do you need to check? If I put the string directly in the MultiCell TCPDF prints it ok

Comment: What do you mean by that? Putting the literal string into the call makes a difference? So `$pdf->MultiCell (66, 10, 'some text', 0, 'L', ...` works? Then you really have some issue with your array. But as said before: nothing I or we can say, since you did not post your code. We may be good, but we are not that good :-)

Comment: I don't know what kind of code do you need @arkascha but I'll be edit the post with the code. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Well, we'd need the stripped down version of the code that creates your PDF, obviously. Leave away not relevant parts, best make a minimal proof of concept that demonstrates your issue, so that we can play around with.

Comment: Try to replace $strech parameter to 1 (currently 4).
Tcpdf code is hard to understand, too much parameters for only one function :D
I personally gave up with tcpdf and now use wkhtmltopdf, that is greatly better (but was requiring a dedicated server).

Comment: Hi @Loenix and thanks you too! If I switch the $strech parameter to 1 TCPDF outputs like an empty string... I used to use FPDF but in the office are using TCPDF :(

Comment: Can't see how document and page are defined in that.

Comment: Try to debug your thing. user echo $row['descripcion'].'<br>' juste before the MultiCell call. try to use 0 as width. Try a very large width. You max height parameter is 0 and from the manual, it should not. Try a very high value, replace the last 0 by 100.

Comment: I've tried all this things but no one works, printing `echo $row['descripcion']` shows the description but when I put this variable into the MultiCell line it breaks out...

Answer (score 1):

Hi everyone and thanks for you help!

I solved my issue. Now the MultiCell or Write function of TCPDF is showing all the data. The solution was to add the utf8_encode function that way: `$pdf->MultiCell (67, 10, utf8_encode($row['descripcion']), 0, 'L', false, 1, 75, 38, true, 4, false, true, 0, 'T', false);`

Hope is usefull for somebody!

Answer (score 0):

In my case TCPDF reacted the same way when I passed invalid UTF-8 string to it. Using mb_substr($text, 0, $max_length, 'UTF-8') instead of mb_substr($text, 0, $max_length) solved the issue. I'd suspect your solution (utf8_encode) intermittently fixes the error that occurred earlier in the code.